# how I send HTTP header with "grant_type=client_credentials"

Tags: javascript, rest, http, https

I am trying to sign up new user on a REST API, and the request should be in this way:

```js
POST /api/oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Basic YW75cm9pZC12tb28Jp8bGU6c2Vj

grant_type=client_credentials&scope=write
```

Question 1: the Authorization code is static it must be the same every time I request a new user or I should generate a new base46 code every time?

Question 2: The grant_type.... is a parameter request or a body ( shall I send it with the body or as a parameter)

Very big thanks in advance!

Comment: These questions need to be aimed at the company's who's API you are using

Answer (score 6):

First, from the *request* code that you provide:

```
POST /api/oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Basic YW75cm9pZC12tb28Jp8bGU6c2Vj

grant_type=client_credentials&scope=write
```

It seems to me that the *request* is for acquiring a client (app) access token (using [`OAuth Client Credentials Grant`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-40)), rather than a *request* to sign-up a user. So, I'm basing my answer bellow on this assumption.

> **Question 1**: the Authorization code is static it must be the same every time I request a new user or I should generate a new base46 code every time?

In the case of `OAuth Client Credentials Grant`, the `Authorization` header contains the client authentication information (e.g, `client_id` and `client_secret`). You usually get this information by registering your client (application) with the API provider.
So the answer is, YES, it should be static as long as the information (the client_id/secret) doesn't change/ expire.

> **Question 2**: The grant_type.... is a parameter request or a body ( shall I send it with the body or as a parameter)

The `OAuth spec` *specifies* that `grant_type` parameter is written in the HTTP request entity-body, so it *should be* sent in the request body. But, some implementation does allow passing the `grant_type` parameter in url too.

Answer (score 3):

**Question 1:** Usually you should use a public token (in this case Basic oauth token) and when this token expires then you should renew it. In the documentation of your api it should exists the time to expire the token and perform a token refresh.

**Question 2:** Looking your information "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=write" it's a body param request (is a post request with a body)